# Spacing after footnote superscript

Tags: spacing, footnotes, glossaries, superscripts

I'm writing my thesis for my Computer Science degree. I have a lot of footnotes and my advisor has told me to remove the spacing generated by the superscript of the footnote.

This footnotes are generated using the glossaries package using the option:

```
\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc,style=long3col,footnote,acronym]{glossaries}
```

this makes that the first time a glossary entry is mentioned it's added as a footnote.

This is how it looks:

Acimut<sup>1</sup> : Explanation

And this is how I want it to look:

Acimut<sup>1</sup>: Explanation

without the space after the superscripted 1, is there a way to achieve this.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc,style=long3col,footnote,acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\gls@main@displayfirst}[4]{
  #1#4\protect\footnote{#2}
}
\makeatother


\newglossaryentry{acimut}{
  name=acimut,
  description={En náutica, el acimut es el ángulo o longitud de arco entre el punto cardinal norte en sentido horario de $0^\circ$ a $360^\circ$ y otro punto.}
}

\begin{document}
\Gls{acimut}, en la figura podemos ver un ejemplo.

\printglossary[type=main,toctitle={Glosario}]
\end{document}
```

produces:

Acimut<sup>1</sup> , en la figura 2.2 podemos ver un ejemplo.

and shoud produce:

Acimut<sup>1</sup>, en la figura 2.2 podemos ver un ejemplo.

Answer:

I figured it out, it was just a small mistake in my command to show the first appearance of a glossary entry in a footnote, it should be:

```
\renewcommand{\gls@main@displayfirst}[4]{
  #1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
\makeatother
```

without that extra line before the }

Thanks

Comment: Under "normal" circumstances, that space shouldn't be there, unless explicitly added. Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating how your footnotes generate the extra spacing?

Comment: Edited to note I'm using glossaries package

Comment: I figured it out, it was just a small mistake in my command to show the first appearance of a glossary entry in a footnote, it should be:

    \renewcommand{\gls@main@displayfirst}[4]{
      #1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
    \makeatother

without that extra line before the }. I would have answer my own question but I can't due to reputation.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a spurious trailing space in the redefinition of `\gls@main@displayfirst`. Replace

```
\renewcommand{\gls@main@displayfirst}[4]{
  #1#4\protect\footnote{#2}
}
```

with

```
\renewcommand{\gls@main@displayfirst}[4]{
  #1#4\protect\footnote{#2}%
}
```

(notice the `%` character at the end of the second line).